# Replace ETL direct integration with WSO2 technology and approach

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have 2 .NET applications with SQL Server databases, systems A & B
System A now directly connects to system B through a database – database approach (ETL). The ETL package reads data from system A database and copy it to system B database after doing some transformations & aggregations. The integration is ok and life is easy.

Our company introduced WSO2 middleware ESB and decided to avoid any direct integration between any two systems, therefore, the integration above should be redeveloped utilizing WSO2 integration technologies and should go through the middleware.

My question: what is the best architecture / design to implement this scenario using WSO2?

1. ETL reads data from system A, then places it in the middleware, then system B reads from middleware database? What is the value added here?
2. Middleware connects to system A, saves the data in a temp storage inside the middleware, then system B reads from that temp db in middle, then purges data? What is the value added here?
3. Some Middleware component (is there any for WSO2) reads data from system A, and do the transformations required, and then stores it in system B?  is that possible?
4. Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Saving data in the WSO2 ESB is not a good approach as main responsibility of the ESB to do the mediation. Lets see how we can use other WSO2 products and fullfill the requirement.

If your requirement is to avoid direct integration to the database. You can use WSO2 Data Services Server [1] and expose your current databases as an API such as REST Services. So your software applications could integrate via REST. In this approach your system A and B connects to WSO2DSS in order to connect DB. If you have a further requirement to connect A and B then you can use WSO2ESB and connect System A,B and WSO2DSS to the WSO2ESB.

Role of the WSO2DSS is to expose your databases as services and it does not support ETL operations. If you want to do ETL operations and analytics operations such as batch analytics, real time analytics and etc, in that case you need to use WSO2DAS [2] and its a totally different implementation.

[1] https://wso2.com/products/data-services-server/

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/WSO2+Data+Analytics+Server+Documentation